# How to use COUNTX to find number of occurences of variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot, dax

This question pertains to PowerPivot.

I am currently designing an invoices table to include a column called "Hits", which counts the amount of times a single customer has purchased one item.

I currently have a table like so:

INVOICES

```
INVOICE ID     CUSTOMER ID      PRODUCT ID       
321            1                444                
322            2                411
323            3                221
324            4                321
325            5                444
326            5                444
```

This is what I would like it do look like:

INVOICES

```
INVOICE ID     CUSTOMER ID      PRODUCT ID         HITS
321            1                444                1
322            2                411                1
323            3                221                1
324            4                321                1
325            5                444                2
326            5                444                2
```

As you can see, the row "hits" calculates how many times that particular customer has ordered that particular product.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in columns A, B and C try this formula in `D2` copied down

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2)`

That gives you exactly what you want - a count of rows where customer and product both match the current row

Comment: Hey Barry, I failed to mention that I am doing this in PowerPivot. I have edited my question to reflect this now. Sorry to waste your time. Any ideas of how to do this using PowerPivot-compliant language?